# Scraping Power BI Dashboard with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm having trouble scraping a [Power BI Dashboard](https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNzA0MGM4NGMtN2E5Ny00NDU3LWJiNzMtOWFlMGIyMDczZjg2IiwidCI6IjM4MmZiOGIwLTRkYzMtNDEwNy04MGJkLTM1OTViMjQzMmZhZSIsImMiOjZ9&pageName=ReportSection) using Selenium. I scrape the url correctly it seems and have good code structure, but the code fails to successfully parse all column after the first (Job Name).

I don't need to click on anything, just scroll down the page to extract all data.

The length of the state data is only 150 while the job name is 362. And then the following column, Licensed, Registered or Certified by the State only returned a len(licensed_data) of 62. I stopped putting in the scroll code as I receive the above errors before getting vey far. I keep the div the same as the page has the same html structure throughout.

If anyone could help me understand why I'm messing up, that would be much appreciated. Again, I'm only trying to scrape the table in the above dash.

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Load the page
driver.get("https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNzA0MGM4NGMtN2E5Ny00NDU3LWJiNzMtOWFlMGIyMDczZjg2IiwidCI6IjM4MmZiOGIwLTRkYzMtNDEwNy04MGJkLTM1OTViMjQzMmZhZSIsImMiOjZ9&pageName=ReportSection")


job_name_data_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Job Name"]')))
# Scroll down to the bottom of the page to load all the data
while True:
    # Scroll down using JavaScript
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(1)  # Adjust sleep time according to your page load speed
    
    # Check if we have reached the bottom of the page
    if driver.execute_script("return window.innerHeight + window.scrollY") >= driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"):
        break

# Extract the text from the Job Name data element after scrolling
job_name_data = job_name_data_element.text

## state
state_column_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="State"]')))
# Scroll down to the bottom of the page to load all the data
while True:
    # Scroll down using JavaScript
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(1)  # Adjust sleep time according to your page load speed
    
    # Check if we have reached the bottom of the page
    if driver.execute_script("return window.innerHeight + window.scrollY") >= driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"):
        break

state_data = state_column_element.text
## license
licensed_column_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Licensed"]')))
while True:
    # Scroll down using JavaScript
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(1)  # Adjust sleep time according to your page load speed
    
    # Check if we have reached the bottom of the page
    if driver.execute_script("return window.innerHeight + window.scrollY") >= driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"):
        break
licensed_data = licensed_column_element.text

len(licensed_data)

## education
education_column_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Education Requirement"]')))
while True:
    # Scroll down using JavaScript
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(1)  # Adjust sleep time according to your page load speed
    
    # Check if we have reached the bottom of the page
    if driver.execute_script("return window.innerHeight + window.scrollY") >= driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"):
        break
education_data = education_column_element.text

## training
training_column_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Amount of Training Required [In Hours]"]')))
training_data = training_column_element.text


## experience
experience_column_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Amount of Experience Required"]')))
experience_data = experience_column_element.text

## pro exam
exam_column_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Professional Exam"]')))
exam_data = exam_column_element.text

## renewal time
renewal_time_column_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Required Time of License Renewal (In Years)"]')))
renewal_time_data = renewal_time_column_element.text

## continious education
continious_education_column_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Continuing Education Requirement"]')))
continious_education_column_element_data = continious_education_column_element.text

## additional exams
additional_exams_column_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Additional Required Exams"]')))
additional_exams_column_element_data = additional_exams_column_element.text

## continious education
cost_of_licensure_column_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Cost of Initial Licensure (In Dollars)"]')))
cost_of_licensure_column_element_data = cost_of_licensure_column_element.text

## license renewal
license_renewal_column_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Cost of License Renewal (In Dollars)"]')))
license_renewal_column_element_data = license_renewal_column_element.text

## reciprocity
reciprocity_column_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Reciprocity or Endorsement"]')))
reciprocity_column_element_data = reciprocity_column_element.text


## character
character_column_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Good Moral Character Requirement"]')))
character_column_element_data = character_column_element.text

## blanket ban
ban_column_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Blanket Ban for Ex-Offenders"]')))
ban_column_element_data = ban_column_element.text

## rehab
rehab_column_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Rehabilitation Requirement"]')))
rehab_column_element_data = rehab_column_element.text

## rehab
rehab_column_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Rehabilitation Requirement"]')))
rehab_column_element_data = rehab_column_element.text

## relationship
relationship_column_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Relationship between Offense and Occupation"]')))
relationship_column_element_data = relationship_column_element.text

##  Limitations
limitations_column_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Limitations on Scope of Inquiry"]')))
limitations_column_element_data = limitations_column_element.text

##  age
age_column_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Minimum Age (In Years)"]')))
age_column_element_data = age_column_element.text
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are multiple problems...

1. You are scrolling the entire page, not just the table containing the data you want.
2. As you scroll >the table< either horizontally or vertically, the elements (rows and/or columns) that move off the screen (are no longer visible) actually disappear from the DOM.

This is going to be a nightmare to scrape.

Having said that, I did write some basic code to get you started. It doesn't even attempt to scroll... only pull what is visible (and then some). It only sees the first 14 cells in each row and the first 20 rows.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

url = 'https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNzA0MGM4NGMtN2E5Ny00NDU3LWJiNzMtOWFlMGIyMDczZjg2IiwidCI6IjM4MmZiOGIwLTRkYzMtNDEwNy04MGJkLTM1OTViMjQzMmZhZSIsImMiOjZ9&pageName=ReportSection'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

table = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@role='document'][.//div[text()='Job Name']]")))
headers = table.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[role='columnheader']")
headers.pop(0) # clean up first header
# print(len(headers))

h = []
for header in headers:
    h.append(header.text.strip())

print(h)

rows = table.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[role='row']")
rows.pop(0) # clean up empty row
for row in rows:
    cells = row.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[role='gridcell']")
    if cells:
        cells.pop(0) # clean up empty cell
    # print(len(cells))
    c = []
    for cell in cells:
        c.append(cell.text)

    print(c)
```

The output

```
['Job Name', 'State', 'Licensed, Registered or Certified by State', 'Education Requirement', 'Amount of Training Required (In Hours)', 'Amount of Experience Required', 'Professional Exam', 'Required Time of License Renewal (In Years)', 'Continuing Education Requirement', 'Additional Required Exams', 'Cost of Initial Licensure (In Dollars)', 'Cost of License Renewal (In Dollars)', 'Reciprocity or Endorsement', 'Good Moral Character Requirement']
['Athletic Trainer', 'Alabama', 'Licensed', 'A bachelor’s degree is required (from an accredited academic institution or similarly recognized institution)', '0', '0', 'Yes, individuals must take an exam to attain licensure', '1', '26 hrs x 1 yr', '0', '505', '75', 'State does have statutory language allowing reciprocity or endorsement agreements', 'State does not have a “good moral character" clause']
```

... and so on